# Test if Item of a VBA dictionary is equal to a given value without adding key and item to the dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

I need to test if the Item of a VBA Dictionary is equal to a given value, without adding a new key and value to the dictionary.

```
dict.RemoveAll
MsgBox dict.Exists(key)
```

MsgBox dict.Exists(key) returns false, the dict is empty.

```
var = "Hello"
MsgBox var = dict(key)
```

The MsgBox returns false, because var and the item returned by dict(key) is not equal. But when I again check if the key exists in the dictionary, dict.Exists(key) now returns true.

```
MsgBox dict.Exists(keys)
```

Seems to me the equal-Operator not only compares var with the item, but also assigns a new key and item pair to the dict, but i need the dictionary still to be empty. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Well, that's pretty interesting. Lots of good information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910996/scripting-dictionary-lookup-add-if-not-present-with-only-one-key-search

Comment: @BigBen  Sub ScriptingDictionary()

Dim Dict As Object
Dim Key
Dim Var

Key = 1
Var = "Hello"
Set Dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Dict.RemoveAll
Debug.Print Dict.Exists(Key)
Debug.Print "CNT=" & Dict.Count
Debug.Print Var = Dict(Key)
Debug.Print "CNT=" & Dict.Count
Debug.Print Dict.Exists(Key)
Debug.Print "CNT=" & Dict.Count
Debug.Print Dict(Key)
Debug.Print "CNT=" & Dict.Count

End Sub

Comment: If you assign a variable to be a non existent key's item pair it creates that key with an empty item pair, or in this case just comparing the values.

Comment: `Scripting.Dictionary`s are [wonky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437731/dictionary-is-populated-with-an-empty-item-after-checking-dictionary-item-in-wat).

Comment: Yes. There might be some weird technical reason for this behavior, or maybe it was just a strange choice by the designers of the language. Anyway, I have used dictionaries for many years without problems and frankly forgot about this behavior, nor did it ever prove to be a problem (yet). This is a weird example where you are checking the value of a key in a dictionary known to be empty -- just don't do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists()` to check if a key exists:

```
Sub foo()

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim key As String
key = "key1"

Set dict = New Dictionary
Debug.Print dict(key) ' -- create a value of Empty for the key
Debug.Print dict.Count ' -- 1 (yikes!)

Set dict = New Dictionary
Debug.Print dict.Exists(key) ' -- no side effects
Debug.Print dict.Count '-- 0 (great!)

End Sub
```

See also (thanks to Cameron Critchlow):

[scripting-dictionary-lookup-add-if-not-present-with-only-one-key-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910996/scripting-dictionary-lookup-add-if-not-present-with-only-one-key-search)

Note in your problem you are creating a variable then checking if it is equal to the value of some key (if that key exists!) - so by extension using the method described above, first check if the key exists, then check if it is the same as your variable:

```
Dim other_key As String
Dim result As Boolean

other_key = "key2"
If dict.Exists(key) Then
    If other_key = dict(key) Then
        result = True
    End If
End If
Debug.Print result
```

Comment: I don't need to check if a key exists, i need to check if the item to a key is qual to a given value and this seems to create a key with an empty item.

Comment: But ... you have to know if the key exists before you try to access the key's value, otherwise you are heading for trouble.

Comment: You are right. And checking if the key exists before comparing will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines will test all keys and items for a match, while not adding any extra keys.

```
    Dim Dict As Object
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dict.Add "test", "this"
    Dim Var As String
    Dim var2 As String
    Var = "test"
    var2 = "this"
    Dim Key As Variant
    
    For Each Key In Dict
        Debug.Print "var - item", Var = Dict(Key)
        Debug.Print "var - key", Var = Key
        Debug.Print "var2 - item", var2 = Dict(Key)
        Debug.Print "var2 - key", var2 = Key
    Next Key
```