# Does anyone have any recommendations for speeding up UFT 14.53 on a Windows 10 platform?

Tags: windows-10, hp-uft, uft14

I've upgraded a laptop (Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1803) and 2 VMs (Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1809) with MicroFocus' UFT version 14.53.  The previous version of UFT was 14.02.

The performance of script execution is annoyingly slow.  Here are some details about the environment:

- Two AUT were developed using J2EE and Angular JS, respectively
- A script that took 18 minutes to run on the laptop is now taking 20 minutes
- The same script is now taking 30 minutes on the VMs
- The scripts are being run in fast mode from the GUI
- The windows 10 machines have been set to Best Performance
- Every time the script starts, the Windows is running low on resources
  popup appears
- The browser on which the app is being run is IE11
- RAM on the laptop is 16GB and 8GB on the VMs

Anybody else experience these pains who can offer any solutions or suggestions?  Unfortunately, our support vendor has been no help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Depending on what kind of object recognition you perform, **there might be noticeable differences depending on how many windows are open on the windows desktop**.

It might be that in you Windows 10 sessions, there are more windows open, maybe invisible, that UFT needs to take account when locating top-level test objects.

For example, opening four unneeded (and non-interfering) browser instances and four explorer instances greatly impacts the runtime performance of my scripts. Thus, I make sure that I always start with the same baseline state before running a test.

To verify, you could close everything you don't need, and see if runtime improves.

2) Do you use `RegisterUserFunc` to call your functions as methods? **That API has a big performance hole**: depending on how much library code you have (no matter where, and no matter what kind of code), such method calls can take more time than you expect. 
I've seen scenarios where we had enough code that one call took almost a second (850 milliseconds) on a powerful machine. 
Fix was to avoid calling the function as a method, which sucks because you have to rearrange all such calls, but as of today, we are still waiting for a fix, after it took us months to proof to MicroFocus that this symptom is indeed real, and really fatal because as you add library code, performance degrades further and further, in very tiny steps. (No Windows 10 dependency here, though.)

3) Disable smart identification. It might playback fine, but it might need quite some time to find out which "smart" identification variant works. If your scripts fail without smart id, you should fix them anyways because your scripts never should rely on smart identification.

4) Disable the new XPath feature where UFT builds an XPath automatically, and re-uses this XPath silently to speed up detection. It completely messes up object identification in certain cases, with the script detecting the wrong control, or taking a lot of time to detect controls.

5) Try hiding the UFT instance. **This has been a performance booster for years**, and I think it still is, see [QTP datatable operations *extremely* slow (much better under MMDRV batch executor)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859323/qtp-datatable-operations-extremely-slow-much-better-under-mmdrv-batch-executo) for info on this, and more.

6) **Certain operations do take a lot of time, unexpectedly**. For example, [Why does setting a USER environment variable take 12 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380389/why-does-setting-a-user-environment-variable-take-12-seconds) completely surprised me.

Comment: Thank you,  great response!  We use RegisterUserFunc a ton, and have massive amounts of functions that get called, so I'm really confident that this bug / performance hog is the cause.  And yes, as the scripts churns on, the performance is visibly slower as it nears completion. Sure hope MicroFocus makes this a top priority!

Comment: Meanwhile, this has changed: The overhead for the calls is gone, but now is observable in the RegisterUserFunc call. This means that if do hundreds of function registrations, the RegisterUserFunc calls can take MINUTES if you have a lot of code in general. This effectively makes RegisterUserFunc COMPLETELY unusable in practice as those calls happen whenever you execute a test. I.e. each test exec has MINUTES overhad before script execution begins. Total fail, if you ask me

Answer (score 3):

Here are things to consider that have been tweaked to speed up my scripts in the past, hadn't had any problems with UFT 12.x on VM machines or VDI's and using Windows 11. I'm just starting with UFT 14.53 on Windows 10. Check Windows 10 for background applications or services that are running prior to even opening UFT or executing a script. In UFT check the Test Settings and UFT Test Options for the following:

Object synchronization timeout - Sets the maximum time (in seconds) that UFT waits for an object to load before running a step in the test.

Note: When working with Web objects, UFT waits up to the amount of time set for the Browser navigation timeout option, plus the time set for the object synchronization timeout. For details on the Browser navigation timeout option, see the HP Unified Functional Testing Add-ins Guide.

Browser navigation timeout - Sets the maximum time (in seconds) that UFT waits for a Web page to load before running a step in the test.

When pointing at a window, activate it after __ tenths of a second - Specifies the time (in tenths of a second) that UFT waits before it sets the focus on an application window when using the pointing hand to point to an object in the application (for example, when using the Object Spy, checkpoints, Step Generator, Recovery Scenario Wizard, and so forth).

Default = 5

Add ____ seconds to page load time - Page load time is the time it takes to download and display the entire content of a web page in the browser window (measured in seconds).

Page load time is a web performance metric that directly impacts user engagement and a business’s bottom line. It indicates how long it takes for a page to fully load in the browser after a user clicks a link or makes a request.

There are many different factors that affect page load time. The speed at which a page loads depends on the hosting server, amount of bandwidth in transit, and web page design – as well as the number, type, and weight of elements on the page. Other factors include user location, device, and browser type.

Run mode - Normal -> or Fast ->

Hope some of this helps, good luck...Aimee

Comment: Windows 11!? From your answer `...VM machines or VDI's and using Windows 11`

Answer (score 2):

You can try Run a Repair UFT installation on Windows 10, see if something was wrong on installation of the uft 14.53.

This worry me a lot, since we gonna change in a couple of days for laptop with Win10.

Try see [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Glance_Troubleshooting.htm) if something can help you.

Regards